# calculate length of list of values associated with each key in nested dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I need to find the length of value list associated with each key of nested dictionaries associated with keys of parent dictionary. Do provide some feedback.

```
dict = {
    "1": { 'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
           'key2': ['value1', 'value2']
    },
    "2": { 'key1a': ['value11', 'value12'],  
           'key2a': ['value13'] 
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: The lengths of the lists are 3 for ["1"]['key1'], 2 for ["1"]['key2'], 2 for ["2"]['key1a'] and 1 for ["2"]['key2a'].

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way.
It prints the key that is associated with the list, and the `len()` of the list which gives the length, so that you know which list has what length.

```
>>> dict = {
...     "1": { 'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
...            'key2': ['value1', 'value2']
...     },
...     "2": { 'key1a': ['value11', 'value12'],  
...            'key2a': ['value13'] 
...     }
... }
>>> for k, v in dict.iteritems():
...     for x, y in v.iteritems():
...         print x, len(y)
... 

key2 2
key1 3
key2a 1
key1a 2
```

This makes use of the [.iteritems()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) function that dicts have

Note that dicts are unordered in Python, so the output might not be in the order you expected.

Comment: I needed to get result set like " 2 ke1a  2 ".
So i used; "print k,x, len(y)" instead.
Thanks...!! this works fine.

Comment: @user3747506 good to hear, you can accept the answer if it helped you